# Magento - default value for admin field

Tags: magento

Is it possible (via programming or xml configuration) to have a default value for a text field admin config option?  If so, how?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add default value to admin config option through **config.xml** file of your module. By admin config option, I understand that you mean configuration settings options (**System -> Configuration**).

Suppose, you have the following **system.xml** file. **System.xml** file is necessary to add admin configuration options.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <sections>         
        <mysection translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>My Section</label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
            <groups>
                <mygroup translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>My Group</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <myfield translate="label comment">
                            <label>My Field</label>                         
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </myfield>                      
                    </fields>
                </mygroup>
            </groups>           
        </mysection>            
    </sections>
</config>
```

Now, to add default value to the admin configuration options, you need to write the following in **config.xml** file of your module.

```
<default>
    <mysection>
        <mygroup>                
            <myfield>My Default Value</myfield>         
        </mygroup>      
    </mysection>
</default>
```

Hope this helps.

For detail explanation, you may refer to:- http://alanstorm.com/magento_default_system_configuration_values

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I've flushed my cache, storage cache, logged in and out, cleared browser cache. What else must I do to make defaults work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<default>
    <catalog><!-- tag of the system.xml section -->
        <frontend><!-- tag of the system.xml group -->
            <name_of_your_field>4</name_of_your_field><!-- tag of the system.xml field -->
        </frontend>
    </catalog>
</default>
```