# Setting default values for a password field in Magento system configuration

Tags: xml, magento, encryption, configuration, passwords

Setting default values for System Configuration fields is well understood (via [Chapagain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846393/336905) and [blog post](http://alanstorm.com/magento_default_system_configuration_values) from @alan storm) but password fields are different because they are encrypted when saved to the database. Hence when Magento reads the default value from the config.xml, it tries to decrypt the value and fails if the default is in plaintext.

Is there an XML helper or process (other than creating a setup script to with `$setup->setConfigData('config/path/here', md5('default'))` ) to specify these defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting question / thought experiment, but the current behavior seems reasonable. If data storage for a value requires encryption, I can't imagine it being appropriate for a functional value to be present in plain text anywhere in the filesystem, whether in config.xml or in an install/upgrade script.

The only other option, encrypting it yourself, is likely undesirable, as you would have to be hand out and therefore be aware of the crypt key value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure (this was a quick `grep`), but I think the password encryption happens in

```
File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php 
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = (string)$this->getValue();
    // don't change value, if an obscured value came
    if (preg_match('/^\*+$/', $this->getValue())) {
        $value = $this->getOldValue();
    }
    if (!empty($value) && ($encrypted = Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($value))) {
        $this->setValue($encrypted);
    }
}
```

Remember, this is an encryption, not hashing. Since you're storing a password to use somewhere (payment APIs most often), Magento needs to be able to unscramble what's been scrambled. So you can generate these values using the `encrypt` method of the core helper.  You could also try something like this

```
$o = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted');
$o->setData('value','encrypted or unencrypted value');

$o->beforeSave();     //to encrypt the value

$o->afterLoad();      //to unencrypted the value

$password = $o->getValue();  //fetch the value
```

Just remember that each store has its own encryption key, so this wouldn't be useful for distributing modules.

You should also look into the [`backend_model`](http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables) attribute (self link disclaimer, not documented anywhere else on the internet) in `config.xml` loading and processing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: TIL there is a public wrapper for _afterLoad... Unfortunately not the case for _beforeSave though :)